# Error: Call to undefined function execute()

Tags: php

this my html and php coding

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Room Size:</label>
          <select class="form-control" required>
            <option value=""> -Sila Pilih- </option>

     <?php

       $sql1    = "SELECT * FROM room_type ORDER BY code ASC";
       $query1  = $conn -> prepare($sql1);
       $query1  = execute();

       while($data1   = $query1 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):
       echo '<option value= "'.$data1->code.'" > '.$data1->title.' </option>';

     endwhile;

     ?>

          </select>
</div>
```

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function execute() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/Kelas/room.php:124
>
> Stack trace:
>   0 {main}
>     thrown in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/php/Kelas/room.php** on line **124**

Comment: change to `$query1->execute();`

Comment: Use it like `$query1->execute()` Read http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: This could help you: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 5):

You should call `execute()` method on `$query1` object which is `PDOStatement` instance.

Try:

```
$query1->execute();
```

instead of:

```
$query1  = execute();
```

Here's [PDOStatement's doc page with examples](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Answer (score 1):

Change the portion of your code

```
$query1  = execute();
```

to

```
$query1->execute();
```

`execute()` method should be called on PDOStatement object `$query1`

Check [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) for detailed explanation.